# General inequality with powers

Tags: inequality

If $x,y\geq0$ and $b\geq1$. Does the inequality $(x+y)^b$ $\geq$ $x^b+y^b$ always hold? If so does this inequality happen to have a name?

Comment: If the $b$ is a positive integer, then it's trivial by Binomial theorem.

Comment: $(x+y)^b=x^b+\text{...non-negative terms...}+y^b\ge x^b+y^b$ so yes, it does always hold (under the assumptions you named).

Comment: @Stef Assuming $b$ is an integer.

Comment: What if b is a non integer?

Comment: It's still true if b isn't an integer. b<c implies z^b <= z^c if z >= 1 (and the reverse if 0<=  z <= 1.  So holds for all the values between integers as well.